# cefsharp winform browser , how to get properly hole website loaded event (some event not working )

Tags: winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

My project in using `cefsharp winform browser` 
There are not properly working `OnLoadingStateChanged`  event 
after opening some website this event 2 or 3 times trigger

I have no idea how to use properly code for hole website properly loaded then i get event

i am using VS 2015 Community
package version  of cefsharp

[all packages installed screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tctgk.png)

project dot net framework is 4.6.2

This is code i am using

```
    public partial class BrowserWin : UserControl
    {

        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        public bool IsLoading;

        public BrowserWin() {
            InitializeComponent();

            CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;

            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            this.Controls.Add(browser);

            //Wait for the page to finish loading
            browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
            browser.FrameLoadStart += Browser_FrameLoadStart;
            browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;

        }

        private void OnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.IsLoading == false)
            {
                IsLoading = false;
            }
        }

        private void Browser_FrameLoadStart(object sender, FrameLoadStartEventArgs e)
        {
            IsLoading = true;
        }

        private void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: `LoadingStateChanged` is the best method to use, remember it's a state change. As per the documentation `This callback will be executed twice -- once when loading is initiated either programmatically or by user action, and once when loading is terminated due to completion, cancellation of failure`. This will occur for each navigation. What are you trying to do when loading has finished?

Comment: Ok i try but not properly work when open following url
https://www.agmachinery.co.uk/used-machinery/?pagination=100&page=1
please helpme

Comment: What does not work probably mean? What are you try to actually do?

Comment: i made code for when website properly loaded then i need event of loaded , here problem is loaded page then reload again so first time event trigger of full loaded page ,

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Ok Thanks , i got it ,
````
                while (browser.GetMainFrame().Browser.IsLoading)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
````
working well